# MySQL efficiently mark duplicates in a large table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-update

I am working on a large table with many events getting data in. I want to check specific column (text or varchar) inside a single event for duplicates and in every row with duplicate occurring set column `duplicity` to 1. As there are currently over 100 000 lines in the table, with about 30 000 lines belonging to the event in question, any joins with subqueries take minutes to finish.

Here is what I came up with so far; it works but still takes several seconds to finish and I'd like to learn a more efficient solution. Also it feels too bulky and ugly for this relatively easy task.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2
;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE ide = 123)
;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table3
;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table3 AS (SELECT id,odpoved FROM table
    WHERE ide = 123
    GROUP BY text_column
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
;
UPDATE (
    SELECT all.id id FROM table3 txt
    INNER JOIN table2 all ON all.text_column = txt.text_column
) a 
INNER JOIN table main ON main.id = a.id
SET main.duplicity = 1
```

This currently takes about 8 seconds, I expect the amount of data in the event to at least triple shortly.

I cannot modify the existing database or table structure.

My previous approach - nicer, but took about 4 minutes on the current data set:

```
UPDATE table t1
JOIN (
  SELECT id,text_column FROM table
    WHERE ide = 123
    GROUP BY text_column
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
ON t1.text_column = t2.text_column
SET t1.duplicity = 1
```

Comment: How often would you be accessing this duplicate data?  If not often, you could just do the calculation when an actual query comes in.  In any case, your duplicate data could become stale at any point.

Comment: I do this once a day after data import; however I can't afford getting the system stuck for long because it's relied on by other applications and users.  I have to do this during peak usage of the system. While the query is being executed, it stops responding to any other requests.

Comment: Also what do you mean by data becoming stale?

Comment: I didn't know you only update once per day.  I recant my comment about stale data.  By the way, I think using a temporary table to do the aggregation and then join updating is good.  Is 8 seconds too long?

Comment: It is OK, but once I get over about 15 secs it starts to be a problem, which I expect when there is several times more data to join on text column - and if I stop it, I may have data corruption because the longest process is on the UPDATE query. I would love to have a working solution where the most time consuming tasks are done before UPDATE starts. But mainly I was thinking whether my solution is OK, since I'm not so good at MySQL and this seems very different to every other solution I found online, so I was worried I'm doing something wrong/missing something better.

Comment: Check the @shadow answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not care how many duplicate records you have, you can use `exists` with subquery to find duplicates:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.duplicity = 1
WHERE ide = 123
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.text_column=t2.text_column and t1.id<>t2.id and ide=123)
```

It also helps if you have a multi-column index on `text_column`, `ide`, and `id` fields.

Comment: This is unfeasible – on the current data set I killed it after 9 minutes of processing. You may be onto something with the multi-column index, but unfortunately a) I can't alter the table and b) different events put their supposedly-unique data to different columns, so I'd have to create several pairs of id-text, or triples of id-ide-text, which would probably hinder the insert and update performance. I'm only guessing here though.

Comment: I was not talking about a unique index, but an index that can speed up the queries.

Comment: I meant supposedly-unique data as in data that I'm checking for duplicates.